# ARMv8 Advanced SIMD: "invalid addressing mode at operand 2 -- `st1 {V1.D}[0],[x20,640]'"

Tags: assembly, memory, arm, neon, armv8

I am trying to store 64 bits to memory from a V register to an address held in an X register but I get the error, "invalid addressing mode at operand 2 -- `st1 {V1.D}[0],[x20,640]".

From the *ARMv8 Instruction Set Overview*, the operation should look like this:

> ST1 {Vt.<\T>}[index], vaddr 
>     Store single 1-element structure from one lane (of one register)
>
> > All SIMD load-store structure instructions use the syntax term **vaddr** as shorthand for the following addressing modes: [base] Memory addressed by base register Xn or SP. [base],Xm Memory addressed by base register Xn or SP, post-incremented by 64-bit index register Xm. [base],#immMemory addressed by Xn or SP, post-incremented by an immediate value which must equal the total number of bytes transferred to/from memory.

Below is the code concretely showing what I am trying to accomplish. To me, it looks like it should be fine.

```
__asm__ volatile (
   "MOV V0.D[0], %[A_MASK]      \n\t"
   "ST1 {V0.D}[0], %[D]         \n\t"
   :
   : [D] "m" (<pointer>), [A_MASK] "r" (0xFF000000)
   : "memory", "V0"
);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`st1` does not take an offset so `[x20,640]` is illegal. Only `[x20]` and similar would be legal. To force gcc to generate a proper address use the `Q` constraint which [the manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html) defines as

> A memory address which uses a single base register with no offset

Note that gcc has vector support so you might not need to use assembly for this.